# rails 3.1 and heroku : routes modifications and problem removing the public/index.html

Tags: ruby, heroku, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is a problem while changing the target of the :root of my rails 3.1 project :

I updated my config/routes.rb to point the root to a custom page.

```
root :to => 'pages#home'
```

Then, I removed the existing public/index.html.
Everything is ok in local.

I ran `git commit -am "message"`, the result was :
`delete mode 100644 public/index.html`

I also committed my new routes.rb and the needed controllers and views.

I pushed to heroku : `git push heroku master`
And then I ran `heroku rake routes` the result was :

```
pages_home GET /pages/home(.:format)       {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
pages_formations GET /pages/formations(.:format) {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"formations"}
pages_music GET /pages/music(.:format)      {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"music"}
        root     /                           {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
        home     /home(.:format)             {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
  formations     /formations(.:format)       {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"formations"}
       music     /music(.:format)            {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"music"}
```

But if I go to my application page, I have an empty white screen.
If I reset the public/index.html, I have this one displayed.

So it seems like Heroku does not take my modifications into account. But the commit works : if I clone the project after deleting the file, I can see that it is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White page usually means you have some sort of error in production. The best way to handle this is to check your production log on heroku with:

```
heroku logs
```

And to address an actual problem.

Comment: 'ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):', this is the error on the server. But I only display static pages and do not use any database.

Comment: You display home action in pages controller, not static page. So, start with that. somewhere your app needs db connection. Try migrating or whatever.

Comment: After solving the ActiveRecord problem, I got some problems with assets javascript and stylesheets, and then with templates that did not want to load in my html.erb. So I came back to the beginning and restarted to follow the guide on how to deploy rails 3.1 applications on Heroku [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) ; doing that, I saw that I forgot the '--stack cedar' option the first time I created my application. Now everything works fine.

Comment: My issue was in my view I have a conditional to see if a user has a profile. if Profile.find(session[:user_id])... on dev it works on production it doesn't.